# word wrap and vertical alignment top only for a specific jqgrid

Tags: css, jqgrid

my page has 2 jqgrids

1) jQuery("#gridmain").jqGrid({....

2) jQuery("#gridsub").jqGrid({....

I read that to make the above I need to use:

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    white-space: normal !important;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    height:auto;
    padding-top:2px;
}
```

But what happens is both grids became vertically top aligned.

I need gridmain to be vertically middle aligned while gridsub to be to be vertically top aligned.

Tried : (without success)

```
#gridsub .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    white-space: normal !important;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    height:auto;
    padding-top:2px;
}
```

Oh yes, the whole thing is inside several div

```
<body>
<div id="SubPgOuterDiv">
    <div id="SubPgTopWaveContainer">
       <div id="SubPgTopLogo">
           <img src="images/subpg_top-logo.png" width="294" height="170" alt="logo" />
        </div>
    <div id="SubPgTopWave">
        <div id="SubpgTopMenu">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js" > </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="SubpgHeaderz">
        <img src="images/subpg_header-gallery.png" width="226" height="130" />
    </div>

    <div id="SubpgContentContainer3">
        <div id="SubPgLeftMenu3">
        <table id="gridmain"></table>
        <div id='pagermain'></div>
        </div>
        <div id="SubpgContent2e">
        <table id="gridsub"></table>
        <div id='pagersub'></div>
       </div>

       <div><p class="clear "></p></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Please help...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the class 'ui-jqgrid' has the div which is *outside* of `<table id="gridsub"></table>` and not inside of it. So you should use

```css
#gridsub tr.jqgrow td { ... }
```

or

```css
.ui-jqgrid #gridsub tr.jqgrow td { ... }
```

instead of

```css
#gridsub .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td { ... }
```